# "Secure booting Error! Cause : boot certification verify" when trying to enter recovery and download mode on LG L Fino (D290n)

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, lg

I have LG L Fino (D290N) and I am not able to start Android OS at all. I have tried to enter recovery mode, but unfortunately I am getting an error. Also, I've tried to enter download mode but the same error shows up.

[image]

```
ERROR : boot certification verify
[1060] ------------------------------------------
[1060]
[1060]  Secure booting Error!
[1060]  Cause : boot certification verify
[1060]
[1060] ------------------------------------------
```

How can I enter download mode in order to flash the device?